# Why is padding not calculated inside the height of the display flex container

Tags: html, css

```css
.wrap {
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: column;
}

.row {
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: row wrap;
  background: yellow;
}

group label {
  padding: 1em;
  background: red;
}
```

```html
<div class='wrap'>
  <h2> Header </h2>
  <div class='row'>
    <group>
      <label> Label </label>
    </group>
  </div>
</div>
```

Why is this padding not inside the calculated height of the container.

Comment: I'm not aware of a `<group>` element. Are you thinking of `<fieldset>`?...

Comment: Its for grouping the radio elements, I saw it on some site used.

Comment: I think the website may have led you astray. There is no `<group>` element. There are `<colgroup>`, `<optgroup>` and the deprecated `<hgroup>` elements though. Perhaps the site was using a custom element? Either way, the markup is invalid though the answer below of setting the `display: block;` on the `<label>` element is correct. See [this site](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element) for more details on the available elements.

Comment: What's javascript have to do with it?

Answer (score 2):

Labels are `display: inline` by default. Setting it to (for example) `display: block` fixes it:

```css
.wrap {
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: column;
}

.row {
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: row wrap;
  background: yellow;
}

group label {
  padding: 1em;
  background: red;
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<div class='wrap'>
  <h2> Header </h2>
  <div class='row'>
    <group>
      <label> Label </label>
    </group>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: inline not inline-block. If they were inline-block we won't have the issue